# Running a project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

In Eclipse, running a project is as simple as clicking the run button.

In NetBeans, I'm totally confused.  How do I run the program?  If I print something, where does it go (e.g. the console in Eclipse)?

Thanks!

EDIT: Solved it.  For some reason it was running a different application than the one I had selected.  Anyone know why?

Comment: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html#run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu, see Run > Run to run a project.

On the bottom right, find the output windows, that's where the print will appear.

Comment: You need to have a Main class defined. What message do you get?

Comment: If you have a main class, you can also display the project window (Windows > Projects), find the main class in the tree structure, then right click the node and select run.

Comment: There is a main class in the file.  It just says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Comment: The hammer builds. The green arrow builds AND runs. You probably clicked the hammer only.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same in NetBeans, just klick the "Run" button (you need to have a main class defined though)

The output goes into the "Output" window which is displayed at the bottom of the editor by default.

If you don't see the output window, you can display it using the menu "Window -> Output -> Output"